# Add xsim exercises in table of contents

Tags: xsim

I wanted to know if it was possible to insert the list of exercises in the table of contents via `\tableofcontent`.

For each of my exercises, I use a template like this:

```
\begin{exercise}[subtitle=title I would like to see in the TOC]

blablabla 

\end{exercise}
```

Comment: Are you using the `default` template? If yes the fastest way is to supply a suitable command to the `exercise/heading` option

Comment: @cgnieder I actually use the default template. I read the documentation but I can't find the variable that works for the title with `\section`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with `xsim` and `tocbasic`: [here's a working example](https://www.overleaf.com/read/hqdhdhfhtpqd).

Here's what we need:

1. Telling the compiler that we want a TOC entry for each exercise, using `\DeclareTOCStyleEntry`;
2. Declare a new exercise template with `\DeclareExerciseEnvironmentTemplate` (telling `xsim` that we want to typeset exercises our way).
3. Add a `\addxcontentsline{toc}{exercise}` command inside the template, where you can specify what to write in that TOC entry.
4. Access the exercise's subtitle with `\GetExerciseProperty{subtitle}`

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will stick to that waiting for the bug to be corrected.

Answer (score 1):

You have three choices:

1. redefine the `default` template,
2. locally change the definition of `\subsection*` with the halp of environment hooks, or
3. use the option `exercise/heading` to choose a suitable command instead of the default `\subsection*`.

Before I show the last and easiest choice there are other considerations to make: if we simply change `\subsection*` to `\subsection` the exercises will get subsection numbers *and* exercise numbers:

[image]

I don't think that this is a satisfying solution. Something like

```
\newcommand\addsubsec[1]{%
  \subsection*{#1}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{#1}%
}
```

with `\xsimsetup{exercise/heading=\addsubsec}` seems a better solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xsim}

\newcommand\addsubsec[1]{%
  \subsection*{#1}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{#1}%
}

\xsimsetup{exercise/heading=\addsubsec}    

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Exercises}
\begin{exercise}
  This is the first problem.
\end{exercise}

\begin{exercise}[subtitle=Another Problem]
  This is the second problem.
\end{exercise}

\end{document}
```

[image]